# Como ejecuto un procedure en laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedure

Que tal amigos vengo a pedir de su ayuda, estoy trabajando en laravel 5.4 por algunas cuestiones tengo que ejecutar un procedemiento almacenado que realiza un insert y luero retorna el id del registro guardado, mi duda es como hago para recibir el id que retorna el procedimento despues del insert hasta ahora solo me retorna true o falsa , cabe mencionar que la base de datos esta en mysql.

```
    $id = 'roman';
    $pw = '9141186427';
    $cod = '0';
    $db = DB::connection();
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=servicios', "root", "");
    $sql = $db->prepare('CALL insert_cliente ?, ?, ?');
    $sql->bindParam(1, $id);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $pw);
    $sql->bindParam(3, $cod);
    $sql->execute();
```

Comment: Si estás en Laravel por que estas usando PDO ?? Por que no estas usando Eloquent ??

Comment: Por cuestiones del trabajo no es que yo los quiera usar pero así me lo pidieron en el trabajo. Saludos

Comment: @Bender Como seria con eloquent? lo he intentado y no muestra registros. Me toco que usar DB para que me funcionara.

Comment: @romanmadrigal [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

Intenta de la siguiente manera:

```
DB::select('CALL insert_cliente ?, ?, ?',array($id,$pw,$cod));
```

o

```
DB::statement('CALL insert_cliente ?, ?, ?',array($id,$pw,$cod));
```

Saludos.

Comment: Tuve que hacerlo manualmente con PDO lamentablemente con los métodos de que laravel ofrece no es suficiente. Saludos